# "class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0" while trying to build JavaFX application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, ubuntu-16.04, openjfx

I wanted to download Openjfx for my Java application. I downloaded it with the command

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

I get the following mentioned error.

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728420/class-file-has-wrong-version-54-0-should-be-52-0-while-compiling-javafx-proje) but I only have jdk 8 and openjfx
version 11.0.2 . I have also seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23267734/9668099). I think I have to downgrade openjfx but I'm not able to.

> java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build on 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.18.04.1-b03
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

This is what in the javafx.properties file

```
javafx.version=11.0.2-internal
javafx.runtime.version=11.0.2-internal+0-2019-02-19-093139
javafx.runtime.build=0
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1432210).

Comment: Probably it is being built with java 11 but run with java 8

Comment: You need to install Java11 and set it as Project JDK in IDE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28180983/2000323 or use 1.8 JDK-compatible javafx version.

Comment: I downgraded as @JoséPereda mentioned, now it's working fine. Thanks a bunch.